# Verifying the existence of each variable before adding it to an array

Tags: php, arrays, validation, variables, conditional-statements

I'm pulling data from a dozen different text fields into a single multidimensional array, but I would like for a key to only be created if there are elements to add to it. Example:

```
$colors = array(
  'red'     => $options['red_users'],
  'orange'  => $options['orange_users'],
  'green'   => $options['green_users']
);
```

Let's say there is no data in the 'orange_users' input field. Other than running a conditional check on each variable, e.g...

`if (!$options['orange_users']) {`

...how can I efficiently validate that data exists for each input field I'm pulling from?

Comment: `foreach( $vbulletin->options as $X){...}`

Comment: "Other than running a conditional check on each variable" - a conditional check on each variable is what you need if, indeed, you want to validate that each variable is not empty.

Comment: In your example you are basically copying your array, changing the keys. So in this specific case most efficient would be to use just your original array (or put the whole array unchanged in another array if you are joining multiple arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with a ternary if

```
  $replacements = array(
    'red'     => isset($vbulletin->options['red_users'])?$vbulletin->options['red_users']:null,
    'orange'  => isset($vbulletin->options['orange_users'])?$vbulletin->options['orange_users']:null,
    'green'   => isset($vbulletin->options['green_users'])?$vbulletin->options['green_users']null
  );
```

Then to weed out the empty values just use array_filter

```
  $replacements = array_filter($replacements);
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Although, I noticed you said "easiest." Is that meant to imply it's not the most efficient, or that there is a better way?

Comment: for one you should use the isset (or empty or array_key_exists) to test or you will get runtime notices in the event that it doesn't exist. and this notation you have will return the value for red if the value for red is not set, so it wouldn't make much sense

Comment: the format for the ternary is  `(expression?true value:false value)`

Comment: it is probably the most efficient and straight forward way as well to answer your first question.

Comment: Or... in PHP 5.3 there's a shorter version: "Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise."

Comment: @jordojuice Cool I didn't know about the truthy part of that returning the value. But in the event of an isset test as the comparison it would return the results of the test instead of that value of the variable in the test.... right?

Comment: for example `isset($myvar)?:false` would return either true or false as opposed to $myvar or false.

Comment: Yep, I believe that's right. Just be mindful of compatibility issues when using this. I ran into that problem before. Wasn't paying attention and got some bug reports on PHP 5.2. My work is still stuck in the past... :-)

Comment: @Orangepill I see. So is there a reason I couldn't do something like **`isset($vbulletin->options['orange_users'])?'orange'=>$vbulletin->options['orange_users']:0`** instead?

Or how would I go about not setting a key -- as the original question asked -- if there's no user data to put in it as an element/value?

Comment: The easiest is to set as is updated then call array_filter on the results.

Comment: Oh god, array_filter is everything I wanted. Thanks!